# Cron jobs in Debian / Ubuntu Docker Swarm Summary

Tags: debian, cron, docker

I wanted to know how to configure a separate cron job container in my docker swarm in order to execute cron jobs in a separate process / container. I'd like to sum up some knowledge I gathered form several posts until I got all my cron jobs working in docker swarm. Please add improvements in comments, or edit them directly if you can.

This was tested with docker 17.04 and a debian:jessie container for cron jobs.

Answer (score 1):

**build**

*Dockerfile* for cron job container, installs cron, starts cron service on container start, then keeps container running with tail command

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -yes cron
CMD service cron start && tail -f /dev/null
```

**composition**

*docker-compose.yml*

```
services:
  cron:
    image: debian:jessie
    volumes:
      - mycronjobs:/etc/cron.d
```

**job files**

in your project root path have a folder containing your cron jobs (only use underscores for special characters in filename)

```
me@machine:/projectdir$ ls -al
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me  978 Apr 26 17:49 docker-compose.yml
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me 1052 Apr 26 18:06 Dockerfile
drwxrwxr-x  6 me me 4096 Apr 26 16:57 mycronjobs

me@machine:/projectdir$ ls -al mycronjobs
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me  978 Apr 26 17:49 job-dash-bad
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me 1052 Apr 26 18:06 job_underscore_good
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me 1052 Apr 26 18:06 check_running
```

**job definition**

you can have cron jobs in

- */var/spool/cron/crontabs/mycrontab* which are created via cli tool *$ crontab* / a.k.a user crontabs
- */etc/crontabs* which is a system wide collection of crontabs

  - '* * * * *' root /bin/touch /projectdir/system_crontab_works # without 's
- */etc/cron.daily* which is folder containing plain bash scripts running daily
- */etc/cron.d* which is a folder containing system wide cron jobs in files similar to */etc/crontabs*. Files must not contain dashes, only underscores

  - sudo vi /etc/cron.d/system_cron
  - '* * * * *' root /bin/touch /projectdir/system_cron.d_works # without 's
  - sudo chown root:root /etc/cron.d/system_cron